# My bot wont work, and I have gone through the code multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, bots

I have searched the script, multiple times, making everything the same, yet I still haven't been able to fix it. I think its with the trigger and reply, yet it still wont work, it might be because of the joke length, spacing, or fetch lines. If anybody could help me find, or fix this problem in the code, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you, if you try to help fix the problem, and especially thanks, if you find the answer

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="container" id="content"> 
        <p id="out">
        </p>
        <p id="inp">
            <div id="stretchbox">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Message" 
                       id="txt-inp"
                       autocomplete="off"             
                       autocorrect="off"
                       autocapitalize="off" 
                       autofocus="autofocus"
                       spellcheck="false">
                </input>
            </div>
        </p>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        var trigger = [
          ["hi","hey","hello"], 
          ["how are you","how is life","how are things"],
          ["what are you doing","what is going on"],
          ["tell me a joke","can you tell me a joke"],
        ];
        var reply = [
          ["Hi","Hey","Hello"], 
          ["Fine","Pretty good","Fantastic","Wonderful"],
          ["Nothing much","Saying stuff","Staring at my code every time you say something to me","Doing robot things"],
           ["What did one mathbook say to the other? leave me alone! I already have my own problems","Why wouldnt the fish share with anybody? Because it was shellfish","KNOCK KNOCK! Whos there? A ROBOT!","If your American when you enter the bathroom and American when you leave the bathroom what are you while your inside the bathroom? european"],
        ];

        println('Bot: ' + trigger[1][0]);

        var alternative = ["I don't understand, make sure everything is spelled correctly!"];

        let textInput = $('#txt-inp');
        let messageOutput = $('#out');
        let processingStatus = $('<span>Bot: Processing...<br></span>');
        let name = 'You';
        function println(text) {
          let newSpan = document.createElement("SPAN");
          let newLine = document.createElement("BR");
          let textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
          newSpan.appendChild(textNode);
          document.getElementById("out").appendChild(newSpan);
          document.getElementById("out").appendChild(newLine);
          gotoBottom();
        }
        function print(text) {
          let newSpan = document.createElement("SPAN");
          let textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
          newSpan.appendChild(textNode);
          document.getElementById("out").appendChild(newSpan);
        }
        function gotoBottom() {
          window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
        }
        function sendMessage() {
          let data = {
            'reply': textInput.val()
          };
          if (!data['reply']) {
            return;
          }
          println(name + ': ' + data['reply']);
          textInput.val('');
          messageOutput.append(processingStatus);
          textInput.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
          messageOutput.children().last().remove();
          textInput.removeAttr('disabled');
          output(data['reply']);
        }
        $('#txt-inp').keypress(function(e) {
          if (e.which == 13) {
            sendMessage();
          }
        });

        function output(input){
          try{
            var product = input + "=" + eval(input);
          } catch(e){
            var text = (input.toLowerCase()).replace(/[^\w\s\d]/gi, ""); //remove all chars except words, space and 
            text = text.replace(/ a /g, " ").replace(/i feel /g, "").replace(/whats/g, "what is").replace(/please /g, "").replace(/ please/g, "");
            if(compare(trigger, reply, text)){
              var product = compare(trigger, reply, text);
            } else {
              var product = alternative[Math.floor(Math.random()*alternative.length)];
            }
          }
          println(product);
        }

        function compare(arr, array, string){
          var item;
          for(var x=0; x<arr.length; x++){
            for(var y=0; y<array.length; y++){
              if(arr[x][y] == string){
                items = array[x];
                item =  items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];
              }
            }
          }
          return item;
        }
      });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: It would help a lot if you would explain what the problem is.  What are you expecting to see?  What are you actually seeing?

Comment: When I type 'tell me a joke' I expect to see a joke, but when I type 'tell me a joke' it says that it dosent understand what I was asking for and its just the jokes it has an error with, everything else works fine.

Comment: Problem is that you're replacing the `/ a /` with a single space in the input, so "Tell me a joke" becomes "tell me joke" and that doesn't appear in your `trigger` array.  But.  By far the worst issue is your doing `eval` on unfiltered user input.  This is Not a Good Idea™

Comment: How do I fix the `eval` part?

Comment: Just copy the code as-is from the catch block and remove the entire try/catch and replace it with the copied code.